# How to get current time in seconds and adds with player duration in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to get the current time in seconds and adds the seconds with player duration and other double value.

Heres the code I tried but didn't work.

```
let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let now = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
        let start_time = now + player.duration + (myModel.diff * 60)
```

The code for myModel.diff

```
var diff: Double = 1
```

and when I try this code, I'm getting error saying

> Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'TimeInterval' (aka 'Double')

Please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your current code to compile by casting `now` to a Double:

```
let start_time = Double(now) + player.duration + (myModel.diff * 60)
```

However, I'm not completely sure what you mean by "current time in seconds." For example, if the current time is 08:00:03, `now` will be `3`. At 08:01:15, it'll be `15` -- if that is your desired result, you're in good shape.

If your desired result is to get a more complete timestamp (seconds since 1970 is common, for example) of the current time, you can use something like:

```
Date().timeIntervalSince1970
```

Feel free to clarify your question and I can adjust the answer.

Comment: so if I wanna use your second code, can I just add it like `let start_time = Date().timeIntervalSince1970 + player.duration + (myModel.diff * 60)` ?? without any formatter

Comment: You *could* -- but, again, I'm a little unclear on exactly what you're trying to achieve/display. That second one is going to be a *very* big number.

Comment: because I'm trying to insert this variable in dispatchqueue duration. but if I can use your first code, then I'll go with that.

Comment: like this `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + time = start_time)`. so can I use something like this?

Comment: No, that doesn't look right -- shouldn't be using the equals sign in the deadline like that). If you're just trying to run something after the player duration plus whatever your myModel.diff is, you can just do `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + player.duration + (myModel.diff * 60))`. You don't need to calculate "now" -- that's what `.now()` does for you

Comment: but I want to reuse the start_time, or can I use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + start_time)` ?

Comment: Again, that'll be way in the future, because `.now()` already calculates that for you. Maybe if you gave some idea about what you're trying to accomplish, I could guide more helpfully.